# How to determine if a graph has a non-unique topological sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, output, topological-sort

I have created a program that organizes a graph by topological sort given an diagram. I identified 3 results:

- ok
- existing cycles
- missing information

The output of the first two points is correct, but for the third it's not. For example for the graph with 4 vertices and edges: 1->2; 3->1; 3->4; 4->2, the result I obtained is: 3 1 4 2... wrong! What is known is insufficient to conclude this.
Any hints or help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Graph{
    int V;
    list<int> *adj;
    public:
        Graph(int V);
        void addEdge(int u, int v);
        void topologicalSort();
};

Graph::Graph(int V){
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v){
    adj[u].push_back(v);
}

void Graph::topologicalSort(){
    vector<int> in_degree(V, 0);
    for (int u=0; u<V; u++){
        list<int>::iterator itr;
        for (itr = adj[u].begin(); itr != adj[u].end(); itr++)
             in_degree[*itr]++;}
    queue<int> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if (in_degree[i] == 0)
            q.push(i);
    int cnt = 0;
    vector <int> top_order;
    while (!q.empty()){
        int u = q.front();
        q.pop();
        top_order.push_back(u);
        list<int>::iterator itr;
        for (itr = adj[u].begin(); itr != adj[u].end(); itr++)
            if (--in_degree[*itr] == 0)
                q.push(*itr);
        cnt++;}
    if (cnt != V){
        cout << "Existing cycle\n";
        return;}
    for (int i=1; i<(int)top_order.size(); i++)
        cout << top_order[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    int N, L, u, v;
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &L);
    Graph g(N+1);
    for (int i=1; i<=L; i++){
        scanf("%d %d", &u, &v);
        g.addEdge(u, v);
    }
    g.topologicalSort();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read this, it really helps: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thanks I know what I did, I'm only asking for help to understand the pattern and create a way to solve it.

Comment: What would you expect to happen? Your code will (presumably) give a valid topological sort for a given digraph. However, you are saying that both [3, 1, 4, 2] and [3, 4, 1, 2] are valid? So do you want an algorithm to detect non-unique orders?

Comment: Thanks a lot for what you said! I wish that when the algorithm detects non-unique orders it gives the string insufficient in the output. But how do I make the difference between unique and non-unique orders?

Comment: What's the question? You say the output is wrong, but it seems like a valid topo-sort given your input. So what makes it wrong?

Comment: Its because I have to respect a acceptacion criterion and for that type of pattern the output must send "Insufficient".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine whether a directed graph has a unique topological ordering?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198355/determine-whether-a-directed-graph-has-a-unique-topological-ordering)

Comment: I will explore your solution. Bellow @gilleain suggested me to see Hamiltinian path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check that a particular graph has a unique topological sorting, it is apparently enough to check for a Hamiltonian path in the DAG. Quoting wikipedia:

> If a topological sort has the property that all pairs of consecutive vertices in the sorted order are connected by edges, then these edges form a directed Hamiltonian path in the DAG. If a Hamiltonian path exists, the topological sort order is unique; no other order respects the edges of the path. Conversely, if a topological sort does not form a Hamiltonian path, the DAG will have two or more valid topological orderings, for in this case it is always possible to form a second valid ordering by swapping two consecutive vertices that are not connected by an edge to each other. Therefore, it is possible to test in linear time whether a unique ordering exists.

So you just need to get the DAG for the first sorting you find and check that it forms a path that visits all the vertices.

Comment: Thank you I will explore your solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the code given, if you find yourself doing two or more q.push() as a result of one q.pop(), then any resulting sort will not be unique. Checking for this is probably less trouble than checking the resulting DAG for a Hamiltonian path.

This is the same condition as discussed in the comments here: [Determine whether a directed graph has a unique topological ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198355/determine-whether-a-directed-graph-has-a-unique-topological-ordering)